# iMacro/JS RuntimeError 933 when using iimPlay

Tags: javascript, imacros

My .JS file looks like this:

```
iimPlay("LoginWebsite1.iim");
iimPlay("LoginWebsite2.iim");
```

When I exexute it in iMacros @ Firefox, it plays LoginWebsite1.iim perfectly. When it's done and are about run LoginWebsite2.iim, it stops.

**Getting the following error:**

RuntimeError: Error loading page about:blank, line 1 (Error code: -933)

LoginWebsite1.iim and LoginWebsite2.iim looks exactly the same, for now. I am just testing how Javascript can execute my .iim-files but dosen't seem to work.

Same things happend with the following .JS-file

```
iimPlay("LoginWebsite1.iim");
iimPlay("LoginWebsite1.iim");
```

Whats up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing AdBlock for Firefox.

Source: http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19701#p50466